# CentOS7 и сервер 1cv83, как разрешить запись в сетевую папку?

Tags: centos7

Для обмена используется сетевой каталог \server\exch\ (win2003), на сервере CentOS он примонтирован в каталог /media/exch, но при "Проверке подключения" пишет - "Ошибка записи файла в каталог обмена информацией. Проверьте права пользователя на доступ к каталогу.
Техническую информацию об ошибке см. в журнале регистрации."

выгрузка в каталог /home/usr1cv8 проходит нормально

Что нужно сделать, чтобы Сервер1сПредприятия на Centos смог писать в сетевую папку?

Делал так:
chmod 777 /media/exch
но когда смотрю командой ls -l то права не изменились...

Comment: Чем примонтирован? samba?

Comment: mount -t cifs -o username=guest,password= //server/Обмен/Exch /media/exch

Answer (score 0):

разобрался, после -o добавил dir_mode=0777, file_mode=0777